# operator overloading +=

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, deque

I must write operator overloading `+=` but I don't know how to do it correctly (I began to write it a the end of code it wasn't correct so i delete all except you see).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class dek
{
private:
    int *x,na4,kon,n,razmer;
public:
    dek(int m)
    {
        x=new int[m];
        n=m;
        na4=1;
        kon=0;
        razmer=0;
    }
    ~dek()
    {
        delete [] x;
    }
    void v_n(int a)
    {
        if(razmer!=n)
        {
            na4--;
            if(na4<0)na4=n-1;
            x[na4]=a;
            razmer++;
        }
        else cout<<"dek polon\n";
    }

    void v_k(int b)
    {
        if(razmer!=n)
        {
            kon++;
            if(kon>n-1)kon=0;
            x[kon]=b;
            razmer++;
        }
        else cout<<"dek polon\n";
    }

    int size()
    {
        return razmer;
    }

    void u_n()
    {
        if(razmer!=0)
        {
            na4++;
            if(na4>n-1)na4=0;
            razmer--;
        }
        else cout<<"dek pust\n";
    }

    void u_k()
    {
        if(razmer!=0)
        {
            kon--;
            if(kon<0)kon=n-1;
            razmer--;
        }
        else cout<<"dek pust\n";
    }

    void pe4at()
    {
        int i=na4;
        if(razmer!=0)
        {
            while(1)
            {
                cout << x[i] << "  ";
                if(i==kon)break;
                i++;
                if(i>n-1)i=0;
            }
            cout << "\n";
        }
    }

    dek& operator = (dek const& b)
    {
        if(&b!=this)
        {
            delete [] x;
            x=new int[b.n];
            n=b.n;
            razmer=b.razmer;
            na4=b.na4;
            kon=b.kon;
            if(razmer!=0)
            {

                int i=na4;
                while(1)
                {
                    x[i]=b.x[i];
                    if(i==kon)break;

                    i++;
                    if(i>n-1)i=0;

                }
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }

    dek const operator +(dek const& b)const
    {
        dek s(n+b.n);
        s.n=n+b.n;
        s.razmer=razmer+b.razmer;
        s.na4=0;
        s.kon=s.razmer-1;

        if(razmer!=0)
        {
            int j=0,i=na4;

            while(1)
            {
                s.x[j]=x[i];
                if(i==kon)break;
                i++;
                if(i>n-1)i=0;
                j++;
                if(j>s.n-1)j=0;
            }
        }

        if(b.razmer!=0)
        {
            int j=razmer,i=b.na4;

            while(1)
            {
                s.x[j]=b.x[i];
                if(i==b.kon)break;
                i++;
                if(i>b.n-1)i=0;
                j++;
                if(j>s.n-1)j=0;
            }
        }
        return s;
    }

    dek operator +=(dek const& b)
    {

    }
};
```

Comment: What aren't you sure how to do? it looks like you have a start, other than I believe += operators must return a reference

Comment: i dont know what to exactly write here                                dek operator +=(dek const& b)
    {

    }

Comment: @DanF There's no requirement in the language concerning the return type of an `operator+=`.  Good practice does require it, however (just as it requires the operator to have semantics related to those of `operator+`, and that these semantics somehow relate to the concept of addition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the results of `a += b;` should be equivalent to `a = a + b;`;
since you have already defined an `operator+`, you know what these 
semantics are.  Once common practice is to define `operator+=` first,
and then implement `operator+` (usually as a free function) in terms of
`+=`:

```
MyClass
operator+( MyClass const& lhs, MyClass const& rhs )
{
    MyClass results( lhs );
    results += rhs;
    return results;
}
```

You then define `operator+=` to operate directly on the class members:

```
MyClass&
MyClass::operator+=( MyClass const& other )
{
    n += other.n;
    razmer += other.razmer;
    //  ...
    return *this;
}
```

(Although there are good reasons for making it a non-member,
traditionally, `operator+=` is a member.  Probably because `operator=`
is required to be a member.)

Also, traditionally, `operator+=` returns a reference, because this
most resembles the behavior of the operator on built-in types.

Finally, on a completely different issue:  you're missing a copy
constructor (which in your case means a double deletion if you do copy),
and your `operator=` is broken (think of what will happen if the `x =
new int[b.n];` fails and throws an `std::bad_alloc`).  The classical
solution for this would be to implement deep copy in the copy
constructor (using more or less the same logic you use in setting the
variables in your assignment operator), and in the assignment operator,
to construct a copy, then swap the elements.  This isn't strictly
necessary, but whatever you do, you must do the `new` (and anything else
which may fail) *before* changing the values in the object being assign.
(If you do this, the test for self assignment is useless; the need for a
test for assignment is usually a signal that the assignment operator is
broken.)

Answer (score 1):

you need to implement `void add(const dek &other)` - split it out of "+" operator.

you can then implement + as

```
dek new_dek(*this);
new_dek.add(other);
return new_dek;
```

And you can implement `+=` as

```
this->add(other);
return *this;
```

(assuming you change the return type of `+=` to `dek &`)